# How to Quit FTP in a script?

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm attempting to write a .bat file for a simple password reset prompt for users, and the last thing I need to do is to quit, which is not being executed for some reason. The process halts after the connection is made, the quit command is ignored, and has to be typed in manually before the process resumes.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off
Echo Password Reset Process 
Pause
Echo Enter your user ID when asked
Echo ---
Echo Change your password by using this format, including the slashes: 
Echo 'oldpassword/newpassword/newpassword'
Echo ---
Echo You will not be able to see what you type
Echo So proceed carefully!
Echo ---
Echo Begin Your Password Reset Now?
Pause
FTP Server.domain.org
Quit
Pause
exit
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Echo Password Reset Process 
set /P "userID=Enter your user ID: "
Echo Enter your new password by using this format, including the slashes: 
set /P "password=oldpassword/newpassword/newpassword: "
Echo Begin Your Password Reset Now?
Pause
(
echo %userID%
echo %password%
echo Quit
) > passfile.txt
FTP -s:passfile.txt Server.domain.org
del passfile.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch files only contain commands for the Windows shell `cmd.exe`.  If you want to input commands into some other program, you have to use its means to do so.

With FTP, you can use the `-s:filename` switch, see `ftp -h`. So you can create a file, say `ftp-cmd.txt`, with the necessary lines and end it with the line `quit` and then in your batch file call `ftp -s:ftp-cmd.txt`.  That should do the trick.